# Counting an increase in series with changing parameters for each ID

Tags: sql-server, loops, dynamic

I have an dataset which has 12 different values for an ID, and also start and end Values. What I want to initilize is take the start value as my begining argument of loop and end value as the last argument. Search trough values accourding to them, and finding the first consecutive increase.

Below I posted an example dataset:

```
create table #sample_data(
ID  VARCHAR(10), val1 INT, val2 INT, val3 INT, val4 INT, val5 INT, val6 INT, val7 INT, val8 INT, val9 INT, val10 INT, val11 INT, val12 INT, startValue INT, endValue INT  
);

insert into #sample_data values
    (1001,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,7),
    (1002,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,12),
    (1003,0,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12),
    (1004,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,9),
    (1005,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,8);
```

That is the result I expect: 
for the ID = 1001 my startValue is 1 and end is 7 algorith will go through from val1 to val7 to compare each val with the next one and count an increase till it ends.
In this case for 1001 it will be be 0 since series will start with a decrease.
for ID 1002 it will also be 3 (val1 to val4 and it will stop at val5 when a decrease occur)
for ID 1003 it will be 1 since there is only an increase at the begining
for ID 1004 it will be 2 since it starts from 3 and ends at val9
for ID 1005 it will be 2 which is the increase from val4 to val6

I have tried to execute this with writing CURSOR  but since I had more than 300K line of data it took hours to execute. If you have any better suggestion (without using cursor), I will be so thakful.

Comment: I'm confused, why is `ID` 1001` have a value of `3`? The first value is `3` and then `2`, that's immediately a decrease, so shouldn't it be `0`?

Comment: There is no SQL Server 17.9. The latest version of SQL Server is 14.0.3162.1 (SQL Server 2017 CU 15). What version of SQL Server are you using, not which version of SSMS.

Comment: Could you please share your solution with CURSOR

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016  - 13.0.5239.0

Comment: Honestly, the results i get are very different to what you describe. I get 0,3,1,2,2 for the IDs 1001, 1002, etc respectively. For example, you state that the value form should be 1003 0, but there is an increase at the very start `val1` has a value of 0 and `val2` has a value of 3. 3 is great than 0, so why is `1003` not 1?

Comment: I have edited it sorry for typos. :)

Comment: For the cursor solution, basically I have declared 3 different cursors one for ID, one for startVal and one for endVal. I wrote I loop and within the loop an dynamic sql which check every value with the next one .

Comment: For ID `1002` - is it `3` or `4` (`4` should be the correct count)?

Comment: it is 3, it start from one increase till 4

Answer (score 1):

You may try with the following approach. The main part is that each row is transformed into 12-row table, with additional `Increase` column and appropriate `WHERE` clause.

Input:

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData(
   ID VARCHAR(10),
   val1 INT,
   val2 INT,
   val3 INT,
   val4 INT,
   val5 INT,
   val6 INT,
   val7 INT,
   val8 INT,
   val9 INT,
   val10 INT,
   val11 INT,
   val12 INT,
   startValue INT,
   endValue INT
);

INSERT INTO #SampleData
   (ID,val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7,val8,val9,val10,val11,val12,startValue,endValue)
VALUES
   (1001,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,7),
   (1002,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,1,12),
   (1003,0,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,12),
   (1004,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,9),
   (1005,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,1,8),
   (1006,1,2,3,4,4,0,7,0,9,10,0,12,1,12)
```

T-SQL:

```
;WITH PreparationCTE AS (
    SELECT
       s.ID,
       v.Increase,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.ID ORDER BY v.Nmr) AS Rn1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN v.Increase = -1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY s.ID ORDER BY v.Nmr) AS Rn2
    FROM #SampleData s
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES
       (1,  Val1,  CASE WHEN Val1 < Val2   THEN 1 WHEN Val1 = Val2   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (2,  Val2,  CASE WHEN Val2 < Val3   THEN 1 WHEN Val2 = Val3   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (3,  Val3,  CASE WHEN Val3 < Val4   THEN 1 WHEN Val3 = Val4   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (4,  Val4,  CASE WHEN Val4 < Val5   THEN 1 WHEN Val4 = Val5   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (5,  Val5,  CASE WHEN Val5 < Val6   THEN 1 WHEN Val5 = Val6   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (6,  Val6,  CASE WHEN Val6 < Val7   THEN 1 WHEN Val6 = Val7   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (7,  Val7,  CASE WHEN Val7 < Val8   THEN 1 WHEN Val7 = Val8   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (8,  Val8,  CASE WHEN Val8 < Val9   THEN 1 WHEN Val8 = Val9   THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (9,  Val9,  CASE WHEN Val9 < Val10  THEN 1 WHEN Val9 = Val10  THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (10, Val10, CASE WHEN Val10 < Val11 THEN 1 WHEN Val10 = Val1  THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (11, Val11, CASE WHEN Val11 < Val12 THEN 1 WHEN Val11 = Val2  THEN 0 ELSE -1 END),
       (12, Val12, 0)
    ) v(Nmr, Val, Increase)
    WHERE (s.startValue <= v.Nmr) AND (v.Nmr <= s.endValue)
)
SELECT ID, SUM(CASE WHEN (Increase >= 0) AND (Rn1 = Rn2) THEN Increase ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
FROM PreparationCTE
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Output:

```
----------
ID  Count
----------
1001    0
1002    3
1003    1
1004    2
1005    2
1006    3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you were aiming for, you can to that using a select case like this:

```
select result.Id, 
    -- result.resulttext
    LEN(replace(substring(result.resulttext,1, charindex('0', result.resulttext)-1), '1', '')) as finaltesult
    from
    (select ID, 
        case when S.val1 <= S.val2   then case when S.val2  >= S.startvalue and S.val2  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val1 < S.val2 then '2' else '1' end else '1' end else '0' end +
        case when S.val2 <= S.val3   then case when S.val3  >= S.startvalue and S.val3  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val2 < S.val3 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val3 <= S.val4   then case when S.val4  >= S.startvalue and S.val4  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val3 < S.val4 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val4 <= S.val5   then case when S.val5  >= S.startvalue and S.val5  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val4 < S.val5 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val5 <= S.val6   then case when S.val6  >= S.startvalue and S.val6  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val5 < S.val6 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val6 <= S.val7   then case when S.val6  >= S.startvalue and S.val7  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val6 < S.val7 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val7 <= S.val8   then case when S.val8  >= S.startvalue and S.val8  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val7 < S.val8 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val8 <= S.val9   then case when S.val9  >= S.startvalue and S.val9  <= S.endvalue then case when S.val8 < S.val9 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end + 
        case when S.val9 <= S.val10  then case when S.val10 >= S.startvalue and S.val10 <= S.endvalue then case when S.val9 < S.val10 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end +
        case when S.val10 <= S.val11 then case when S.val11 >= S.startvalue and S.val11 <= S.endvalue then case when S.val10 < S.val11 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end +
        case when S.val11 <= S.val12 then case when S.val12 >= S.startvalue and S.val12 <= S.endvalue then case when S.val11 < S.val12 then '2' else '1' end  else '1' end else '0' end  as resulttext
    from @sample_data as S) result
```

This case will transform each transition to:

- '0' is value valN is higher than valN+1
- '1' if value matches the limits but valN is equal to valN+1
- and '2' if the transition from valN to vanN+1 matches all your
  conditions

Than is just a matter of working with the result string.
Uncomment result.resulttext if you want to take a look at the 'transformed' result string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You get the correct result but the thing is your code not looping it from startValue to endValue instead you are comparing the values with start and end which is not really what I asked.